# Delegates: Referring to local variables in the class from which it is called, not defined?

Tags: c#, wpf, delegates

Is it possible to use delegates to essentially add functionality to a class in a reusable way? To do this, you would have to be able to refer to variables in the class that the delegate is assigned to.

Here's what I mean:

```
public delegate void InputHandler(InputManager input);

public class UIElement
{
    public InputHandler ClickHandler;
    private int variableIWantToUse;
}

public class UIManager
{
    private UIElement ui;

    public void AttachClickHandler()
    {
        ui.ClickHandler = BasicClickAction;
    }

    private void BasicClickAction(InputManager input)
    {
        // Can I refer to any of UIElement's variables in here?
    }
}
```

Essentially, I'm having UIElement be as reusable as possible. I'd like some other class that uses a UIElement to be able to "attach" plug-n-play functionality to its UIElement, by defining what happens when it is clicked. But it seems that any function UIManager defines can only refer to its own variables, not UIElement's. Any way to get at UIElement's variables?

Or maybe I am being thick and there is some other way entirely to get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

There is a reason why `Base Class Library` in `.Net` follows `sender/EventArgs` pattern. You should also use it.

### Example (Your code with some corrections):

```
public delegate void InputHandler(Object sender, InputHandlerEventArgs e);

public class InputHandlerEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public InputManager Input { get; set; }

    public InputHandlerEventArgs(InputManager input)
    {
        Input = input;
    }
}

public class UIElement
{
    //public InputHandler ClickHandler;
    public event InputHandler ClickHandler; // Should be an event

    private int variableIWantToUse;

    protected void OnClickHandler(InputHandlerEventArgs e)
    {
        InputHandler temp = ClickHandler;
        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp(this, e);
        }
    }
}

public class UIManager
{
    private UIElement ui;

    public void AttachClickHandler()
    {
        //ui.ClickHandler = BasicClickAction;
        ui.ClickHandler += BasicClickAction; // Making this an event changes this line of code
    }

    private void BasicClickAction(Object sender, InputHandlerEventArgs e)
    {
        UIElement element = (UIElement)sender;
        // Can I refer to any of UIElement's variables in here?
    }
}
```

Comment: Events seem like a fine way to get it to work. However, the model is a little different conceptually (subscribing rather than setting a functionality). I'll probably just stick to using a bare delegate without the event add/remove. That way, I don't have to write the add/remove functions to do what the exposed delegate does naturally.

Comment: I just recommended you use events. But, you better know your scenario. And also, you don't `have to` write `add/remove` functions to make events `work naturally`. `add/remove` accessors are optional.

Comment: I guess I would like to: 1. enforce it to be singlecast, which as I understand the default add doesn't do, 2. Allow it to be set to null, which require a custom add as well, 3. copy the delegate to another UIElement, which requires access to the exposed delegate. In short, direct access to the delegate rather than through events. But I do take your point that events are generally the way to do this. As a side question, why do you create another reference to the event 'temp' and use that, rather than directly call ClickHandler(this, e)?

Comment: FYI: `System.EventHandler` already provides the delegate declaration. You can use the generic version `EventHandler<T>`. The non-generic `EventHandler` is identical to the generic `EventHandler<EventArgs>`. Personally I'm a big fan of using delegate types that are already defined.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common pattern to provide the `sender` (i.e. the `UIElement` or an `object`) as an argument for the handler. Do you really need the manager as an argument? I would go with:

```
public delegate void InputHandler(UIElement sender);
```

Comment: That seems like a pretty good solution. At the cost of always passing itself in as a parameter, and having every variable I would like to use be publicly accessible, that would work. I'm curious if there is any way to just plain add functionality, in a way that would allow it to use private variables as well? I.e. just as if that class had that method?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only access public variables in `UIManager`. To access private ones the method must be in the `UIElement` class.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use polymorphism to allow people to subclass UIElement and override just the methods they would like to customize? Subclasses of UIElement could then access protected data members and methods. Those protected members would effectively be private to any class that wasn't a subclass.

That said, the above responses about the correct pattern for events are good to know. Although one note: you should probably just use the generic `EventHandler<InputHandlerEventArgs>` instead of creating a new delegate type.

Comment: subclassing and overriding is quite rigid. For example, what if I wanted to switch to another behavior during runtime?

Comment: It is true that subclassing does not lend itself well to runtime behavior modification. But many a UI toolkit, such as WPF, rely on the combination of inheritance and events (and composition). I'm curious where your requirement for this runtime change comes from, and if it's really wise. But that said it sounds like you've got your question answered, so best of luck with your project.